# split an arbitrary set s into two subsets of fixed size

Tags: haskell, filter, subset

In order to split an arbitrary set s into two subsets l and r, in which l has a fixed size n, I have written the following code:

```
 parts :: Int -> [a] -> [([a], [a])]
 parts n ls = (filter len . f) ls
  where len (lhs,rhs) = length lhs==n  -- the condition that the left subset is of fixed size n
        f []     = [([],[])]
        f (x:xs) = [ (x:l,r) | (l,r)<-f xs] ++ [ (l,x:r) | (l,r)<-f xs]
```

Here is a sample of its effect. Evaluating  `parts 2 "12345"` yields:

```
[ ("12","345")
, ("13","245")
, ("14","235")
, ("15","234")
, ("23","145")
, ("24","135")
, ("25","134")
, ("34","125")
, ("35","124")
, ("45","123")
]
```

Please notice that my solution enumerates all subsets and then filters out the desired ones. I suppose the subsets function is familiar to you:

```
 subsets :: [a] -> [[a]]
 subsets []  = [[]]
 subsets (x:xs) = map (x:) (subsets xs) ++ subsets xs
```

Personally, I find my solution disappointing. It filters the correct answers from a larger set. My question to the reader is: 
Can you come up with a function that is equivalent to `parts`, but produces the answer directly without this a-posteriory filter?

Comment: It will be helpful if you add the output you are expecting for a sample input.

Comment: @Zeta Then I think I'm not understanding the question properly. :) OP mentions that `Personally, I find my solution disappointing. It filters the correct answers from a larger set.` So I'm thinking that OP is expecting a different answer ?

Comment: He's comparing his function to `Data.List.subsets`, which doesn't use an a-posteriori filter and wants to create something similar for his version: *"Can you come up with a function that is equivalent to `parts`, but produces the answer directly without this a-posteriory filter?"*

Comment: Is it ok if the function reorders the elements in the two subsets?

Comment: @Zeta the example by OP is not sufficient. It only shows one result for one string with odd number of elements. But what about `parts 1 "ab"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by `subsets`, you might end up with

```
import Control.Arrow (first, second)
-- first f (x,y) = (f x, y) ; second f (x, y) = (x, f y)

parts n xs = parts' 0 xs where    
    parts' l (x:xs) | l <  n = map (first (x:))  (parts' (l + 1) xs) ++ -- 1a
                               map (second (x:)) (parts' l xs)          -- 1b
    parts' l xs     | l == n = [([],xs)]                                -- 2
    parts' _ _ = []                                                     -- 3
```

`l` contains the length of the first pair so far. As long as the pair isn't yet long enough, we take the first element of the list, and append it to all first elements in our pairs (1a). We're also going to map it onto the second elements (1b). Note that in this case the length of the first pairs didn't increase.

When the first pairs just happen to be long enough (2), we're going to put all other elements into the second half of the pair.

When the requirements for the guards do not hold (list exhausted), we return `[]` (3). This approach also retains the relative ordering of elements:

```
> parts 2 "12345"
[
  ("12","345"),
  ("13","245"),
  ("14","235"),
  ("15","234"),
  ("23","145"),
  ("24","135"),
  ("25","134"),
  ("34","125"),
  ("35","124"),
  ("45","123")
]
```

This approach will also work on infinite lists:

```
> map (second (const "...")) $ take 5 $ parts 3 [1..]
[([1,2,3],"..."),([1,2,4],"..."),([1,2,5],"..."),([1,2,6],"..."),([1,2,7],"...")]
```

(The second elements in the pairs will still be infinite lists)

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is what I came up with:

```
parts :: Int -> [a] -> [([a],[a])]
parts n list = parts' 0 (length list) [] [] list where
  parts' _  _ ls rs []        = [(ls,rs)]
  parts' n' l ls rs as@(x:xs) | n' >= n     = [(reverse ls, reverse rs ++ as)]
                              | n' + l <= n = [(reverse ls ++ as, reverse rs)]
                              | otherwise   = parts' (n' + 1) (l - 1) (x : ls) rs xs 
                                           ++ parts' n' (l - 1) ls (x : rs) xs
```

If it doesn't matter if the elements of the subsets are in the same order as they were in the original set, then you can remove the four uses of `reverse`.

Answer (score 1):

Sliding split can be done using `zipWith` of `inits` and `tails`. For each split produce the solution for a smaller sublist, and append the element at the point of split to all such solutions.

```
parts 0 xs = [([],xs)]
parts n xs = concat $ zipWith f (inits xs) (init $ tails xs) where
  f hs (h:ts) = [(h:t', hs++ts') | (t', ts') <- parts (n-1) ts]
  -- f hs [] not possible - init $ tails xs does not produce empty lists
```